# use javascript to replace browser ctr + n default handler?

Tags: javascript, browser

I was wondering whether a tricky JavaScript snippet exists, to replace web browsers default Crl+N event handler(they open a new file).
(I know it's a bad boy's job and I also know chances are low.)

Comment: it's a good thing that this doesn't work. cause any website trying to highjack my keyboard should be black listed

Comment: did we answer your question? If so can you accept an answer please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers are designed so that websites run in sandboxes. Preventing anything that goes sour ( maliciousness intended or not ) to not affect the computer itself. So you might be able to change your own browser settings, I doubt you will find an easy way to do this.

In addition you shouldn't do this even if you find a way. IE will let you erase the clipboard, but that doesn't mean doing so wont piss off every user who visits your website.

Why do you want such behavior anyway? I cannot see any amicable reason.

Comment: "I cannot see any amicable reason" - this. It's almost always a bad idea to override expected behaviour.

Comment: It's not my preference too. but that's not my choice. my client want's to see expected behaviour on web as the same as classic native desktop applications. not everyone using a software is a developer

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I just tried it. It doesn't work:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which == 17)
      $(window).bind('keydown.ctrln', function(e){
          if(e.which == 78){
              e.preventDefault();
              alert('CTRL+N');
          }
      });
});

$(window).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which == 17)
      $(window).unbind('keydown.ctrln');
});
```

Changing `e.which == 78` to `e.which == 73` makes it work in Chrome if you press Ctrl+i since Ctrl+i doesn't have any default action in Chrome. But you can't overwrite the default browser behavior, which is what I was guessing was going to happen anyways.

Comment: somehow similar to what I thought was worth giving it a try!